# Windows RDS - Make each users use specific NIC

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, network-adapter, windows-server

I have the following situation:

I have one Windows Server, configured as RDS for 5 users.
These users need to use this RDS to access a specific website, accessed with Pulse Secure.

For multiple reasons, I need each of them to use a specific IP when going to WAN.
e.g:

```
User A --192.168.1.11--> WAN
User B --192.168.1.12--> WAN
User C --192.168.1.13--> WAN
User D --192.168.1.14--> WAN
User E --192.168.1.15--> WAN
```

I have set up the 5 NICs on my server. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Sounds like a case for dedicated Hyper-V VMs.  There is no way to accomplish what you want with a single server.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it seemed to be the way to go, but I was really trying to make a single ressource run on the server, and not 5 

Comment: Is it not possible with NAT rules on your firewall?